# not able to do ajax request in my custom component i'm not working in mvc right now

Tags: ajax

if i go with upload my php file where data is being sent and from where data is getting stored (that php file) stored into server http://ip/includes/js_new/update_contact.php
then it shows 500 internal problem.. pls help me frnds..
         $("#update_btn").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("debugging");
          var data=$("#frmUpdate").serialize();

```
      $.ajax({
       // url:"index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=44",
        url:"http://ip/includes/js_new/update_contact.php";
        type:"POST",
        data:data,
        cache:false,
        success:function(result){
          alert(result);
          console.log(result);
          alert("testting");

           }
         })

        e.preventDefault();

      });
```

**UPDATE**
Guys i got the proble it is working now Thank you so much for your quick replies..
Problem was-- there was error in my php page where i'm posting or written insert and database query... because of that it was not showing error and we just focused on ajax request only it is write. i'v to change on php file.. for ajax we don't need mootool or don't require to follow whole mvc pattern of the joomla... I got it guys i written these every thing for our future developers...

Comment: What's the response you're getting back from the ajax request? Can you check your Network tab in the browser console?

Comment: index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=32&contactType=:454 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validationEngine is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=32&contactType=:454)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: That's the console tab. Please check the network tab, click on the request, and check the response. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnghj.png

Comment: Hi Lodder, thanks for replying me . but i didn't get any response when i click my ajax request button

Comment: can u see my screen using any desk or zoom app

Comment: If the ajax is not triggering, then you'll need to update your question with the code that triggers the ajax request

Comment: can you help me ?

Comment: Please add the code that is triggering the ajax request

Comment: $("#update_btn").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("debugging");
          var data=$("#frmUpdate").serialize();
        

          $.ajax({
            url:"index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=44",
            type:"POST",
            data:data,
            cache:false,
            success:function(result){
              alert(result);
              console.log(result);
              alert("testting");

               }
             })
           
            e.preventDefault();
       
          });

Comment: Is there any one who can help me on these I can implement Ajax using some other frameworks like code igniters core php every where but in joomla there is an issue can you guys help me out me from these issue I'm struggling from a week

Comment: I got the error in network's   header tab
that is 500 internal of that url

Comment: Can you send the entire component so that I can work on it to find what mistake you are doing exactly.

Comment: guyes solved probelm no need to worry about it

Answer (score 1):

Please note that when you are providing an url link you should not use a trailing slash

so instead of `url:"/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=44",`

You should give

```
url:"index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=44",
```

Comment: i did this also it is not working

Comment: if you open the console what error your are getting?

Comment: Pls see my updated comment of my question I posted there

Comment: 500 internal server error

Comment: I think the approach i'm going with is wrong i'v to follow the joomla docs for ajax but i wanted to do like core php or other frameworks but it is not working I'v to follow the whole documentation of the joomla com_jumi and all mootool and all so that i'll achieve.

Comment: You need to first understand how the MVC system works and how joomla component is developed. You need to check this https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component

Comment: sure! thank you
Can you put custom url on ajax like i try to apply. in option field i'm just giving my component name and in fieldid i given my component's file id where i have written my server side interaction programm like inserting data and updating data.
Can you please tell me how to write if it is not working...

Comment: You can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363511/relative-vs-absolute-urls-in-jquery-ajax-requests